# Looping through XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to loop through a XML using PowerShell, but unable to get the `InnerXML` details.

**XML:**

```xml
<script>
    <data>
        <address>
            <street>WhiteField</street>
            <zip>560100</zip>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <country>India</country>
            <postofficebox>BangaloreEast</postofficebox>
        </address>
    </data>
    <data>
        <address>
            <street>Gurgaon</street>
            <zip>601000</zip>
            <city>New Delhi</city>
            <country>India</country>
            <postofficebox>New Delhi West</postofficebox>
        </address>
    </data>
</script>
```

**Script:**

```bsh
[string]$FilePath = 'C:\Users\Sujeet\Desktop\UserData.xml'

try {
    [xml]$XMLInput = Get-Content -Path $FilePath
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to read or parse the XML File."
    exit
}

if ((Select-Xml -Xml $XMLInput -XPath "//address" | measure).Count -gt 0) {
    Select-Xml -Xml $XMLInput -XPath "//address" | foreach {
        $_.Node.InnerXML
    }
}
```

How do I get the values for `<street>`, `<city>`, `<country>`?

Also I want to fetch the details only if the city is "Bangalore".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InnerXml` gives you the content of an XML node as a string. Don't use it if you want to access nested elements. `$_.node` is an object. The child nodes of that object can be accessed like this:

```bsh
Select-Xml -Xml $XMLInput -XPath '//address' | ForEach-Object {
    $street = $_.Node.street
    $city   = $_.Node.city
    ...
}
```

Using dot-access automatically expands the value of a node.

For limiting the results to a particular city add a filter to the XPath expression:

```bsh
$city = 'Bangalore'
Select-Xml -Xml $XMLInput -XPath "//address[city='${city}']" | ForEach-Object {
    $street = $_.Node.street
    $city   = $_.Node.city
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `SelectNodes()` method instead of `Select-Xml`:

```bsh
$city = 'Bangalore'
$XMLInput.SelectNodes("//address[city='${city}']") | ForEach-Object {
    $street = $_.street
    $city   = $_.city
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way:

```
[xml]$xml = "<script>
    <data>
        <address>
            <street>WhiteField</street>
            <zip>560100</zip>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <country>India</country>
            <postofficebox>BangaloreEast</postofficebox>
        </address>
    </data>
    <data>
        <address>
            <street>Gurgaon</street>
            <zip>601000</zip>
            <city>New Delhi</city>
            <country>India</country>
            <postofficebox>New Delhi West</postofficebox>
        </address>
    </data>
</script>"

$addresses = $xml.script.data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty address
foreach ($address in $addresses) {
    if($address.city -eq 'Bangalore') {
        $address.street
    }
}
```